# Efficient way to access constant key value data

Tags: c#, dictionary, keyvaluepair

I am wanting to store key - value data and be able to access it in an efficient manner.

Basically: I have a custom object(EquipmentObj) and w/ in that object is a property called "DeviceType". In the constructor of the object, I am passing a string which goes out to a Dictionary (Local Variable of EquipmentObj) and returns a value if the Dictionary has the key.

In an attempt to minimize initializing the Dictionary 25 times on the heap, (EquipmentObj is instantiated 25-50 times) I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this.

My first thought was XML, but I can't add deserialization; I wont get into this.

My next thought was possibly using a static class. But I still need to define the KeyValuePair or Dictionary and static classes cant have instance members.

What would you all suggest?

Here is a sample of what I am basically doing right now.

```
class EquipmentObj
    {
        public EquipmentObj(string deviceType)
        {
            addItems(); 
            this.DeviceType = EquipmentList.ContainsKey(device_Type) ? EquipmentList[deviceType] : "Default";
        }
        public string DeviceType { get; set; }
        private Dictionary<string, string> EquipmentList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        private void addItems()
        {
            //Add items to Dictionary 
        }
    }
```

Comment: How is the dictionary populated in the first place?

Comment: A static class can have static members. But you don't need that, why don't you just make EquipmentList a static member of EquipmentObj?

Comment: That sound much like micro optimization - don't waste your time with that before it is proven to be a problem, just my advise.

Comment: @Casperah - Normally, I'd agree, and this isn't worth doing just for performance issues. But it *is* better design to make the dictionary `static` in the first place, so it's worth doing for that.

Comment: Does the EquipmentList dictionary represent the equipment included in an EquipmentObj? Or is this something else?

Comment: Thanks guys I have what I need. Making the Dictionary static was a perfect solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `static` class can't have instance members, but a non-static class can have `static` members.  You can make `EquipmentList` and `addItems()` both `static` without changing `EquipmentObj` itself.

```
class EquipmentObj
{
    public EquipmentObj(string deviceType)
    {
        addItems(); 
        this.DeviceType = EquipmentList.ContainsKey(device_Type) ? EquipmentList[deviceType] : "Default";
    }
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
    private static Dictionary<string, string> EquipmentList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static void addItems()
    {
        //Add items to Dictionary 
    }
}
```

You'd call it as:

```
EquipmentObj.addItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could make a Manager class to handle the device types, Its not required but it does seperate the logic and makes accesing the devicetype from other area's in your app a bit easier.

```
public class EquipmentObj
{
    public EquipmentObj(string deviceType)
    {
        this.DeviceType = EquipmentObjManager.GetDeviceType(deviceType);
    }
    public string DeviceType { get; set; }
}

public class EquipmentObjManager
{
    private static Dictionary<string, string> EquipmentList = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    public static string GetDeviceType(string deviceType)
    {
        return EquipmentList.ContainsKey(deviceType) ? EquipmentList[deviceType] : "Default";
    }

    public static void AddDeviceType(string deviceTypeKey, string deviceType)
    {
        if (!EquipmentList.ContainsKey(deviceTypeKey))
        {
            EquipmentList.Add(deviceTypeKey, deviceType);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure where you are population you Dictionary, but you can call `EquipmentObjManager.AddDeviceType` to add Items to the dictionary.

May not be the best solution for you , but it could help :)

Comment: I am populating the dictionary, just left the items out because they are business sensitive.